# Controlar acceso a las subrutas de una web con JWT

Tags: typescript, jwt

Recientemente empecé a implementar el uso de JWT en mi página web que funciona con Angular + Typescript.

He conseguido que dependiendo de los datos del JWT un usuario tenga acceso a una subruta dependiendo de su rol:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: "pruebas", component:PruebasComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {role: 'user'}},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found', pathMatch: 'full' }

];
```

AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
          if (this.storageService.getToken()) {
            const requiredRole = route.data['role'] as string;
            if (requiredRole) {
              console.log(requiredRole);
              console.log(jwtDecode(this.storageService.getToken()));

              let aux: any = jwtDecode(this.storageService.getToken());
              const rol = aux.rol;
              console.log(rol)
              resolve(true);
            }

            else resolve(true);
          }
            
          else {
            
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
              queryParams: {
                return: state.url
              }
            });

            reject(false);
          }
      });
  }
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona correctamente, pero mi duda es no podría generar un atacante un JWT con la propiedad de rol al valor que quiera? Como puedo comprobar de manera segura que el JWT ha sido generado con mi clave secreta?

Nota: Obviamente mis archivos contienen más código pero considero que no es relevante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única forma de comprobarlo es hacer una llamada a tu backend, pero realmente no tienes que preocuparte demasiado por eso si tu aplicación está bien hecha. El flujo habitual es el siguiente:

- El usuario se autentica con su identificador y contraseña, obteniendo un JWT. El token tiene información que es fácilmente visible, pero no se puede modificar porque viene "firmado" desde el servidor.
- Para cualquier petición al servidor requiere que el token sea enviado como parte de la petición (lo más habitual es que sea como un header).
- El servidor comprobará que el JWT no haya sido modificado, analizando la firma. Cualquier discordancia hará que la petición sea denegada.

Por supuesto, en la parte "frontend", un usuario con conocimientos podría modificar el token y acceder a pantallas de la aplicación a las que no debería acceder, pero esas pantallas estarán vacías porque no podrán recabar información y cualquier intento de obtener o modificar datos fallará.

Que el usuario sepa que existen pantallas a las que generalmente no tiene acceso no debería ser nunca un problema (la *seguridad por oscuridad* es una mala política).